# Is it correct to say the the bag is sitting on top of the table?

Tags: grammar

Can you say. The bags are sitting on top of the table?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. The Ngram for 'on top of the table' against 'on the table' shows that, idiomatically, 'on the table' is vastly more common. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+top+of+the+table%2C+on+the+table&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20top%20of%20the%20table%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20table%3B%2Cc0

Comment: But nothing wrong with "on top of the table".   I wouldn't think twice if I heard it.

Answer (score 1):

To me "The bags are on top of the table." And, "The bags are on the table." Are the same, just because my mom says it a lot. Because if you were on top of a bean-bag and someone says, "She/He is on the bean-bag." Its not specifically saying where he/she is at but I'm not going to assume that he/she is defying gratify and he/she is laying on the side of the bean-bag. I'm assuming that he/she is on top.